# amp app banner is not showing on Safari even though working on android

Tags: next.js, amp-html

We recently implemented amp app banner and worked fine on the browsers we tested except for Safari.

In page head we added this:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1234567890" />
```

Under body, first child, we added this markup:

```
<amp-app-banner
    layout="nodisplay"
    id="our-app-banner"
    style={{
        top: '0px',
        height: '40px',
        minWidth: '343px',
    }}
>
    <InstallMobileAppBar />
</amp-app-banner>
```

And this is how we wrote our InstallMobileAppBar component:

```
      <div className="install-mobile-app-bar">
        <div id="install-app-panel" className="install-app-panel">
            <div
                style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    minWidth: '202px',
                    marginRight: '24px',
                }}
            >
                <div
                    style={{
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        textAlign: 'right',
                        marginRight: '5px',
                    }}
                >
                    <div
                        style={{
                            fontSize: '12px',
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                        }}
                    >
                      text
                    </div>
                    <div
                        style={{
                            fontSize: '8px',
                        }}
                    >
                        text
                    </div>

                    <div className="banner-stars">
                        <Star />
                        <Star />
                        <Star />
                        <Star />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="app-banner-logo">
                    <amp-img
                        alt="khareta-banner-logo"
                        src="/images/icons/icon-96x96.png"
                        width="50"
height="50"
                        layout="fixed"
                    ></amp-img>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div
                style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                }}
            >
                <button className="open-button" open-button="open-button">
                    download app now
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Safari 14.0 (15610.1.28.1.9, 15610)
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
macos 10.15.7

AMP version 2010132225003

Comment: Why the braces for `style=`? Just use double-quotes. Also, it's safer to move those elements into `<style amp-custom>`. Further, the `meta` properties are unrelated to content in `<body>`. I'm actually surprised this worked anywhere as-is.

Comment: braces since we use Nextjs, it's a syntax. I'm not sure about amp-custom, will have to look that up. Now the important thing here, you say meta properties are unrelated? 
I'm not sure I get what you mean by that, just keep in mind that all required amp components are properly loaded, I just took snippets of the code. I'd really appreciate it if you elaborate a little bit more.